# Split nsarray into sections by NSDate

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdate

I have an `NSArray` that is extracted from core data. The entities in the array have a `date` attribute (of type `NSDate` ofcourse). What I want to do is this:

- The array needs to be displayed in a table view,
- the sections, and their titles are months , of the objects in the array

For example if I have 3 objects (april 1, april 3 & july 7) there should be 2 sections:
 - april 2012(2 obj)
 - july 2012 (1 obj)).

How do I split the array like this?

Comment: Just a guess:  Iterate through the items, check their dates, and sort into the appropriate buckets.

Comment: If there are hundreds of items, this would be inefficient ...

Comment: How so?  Any solution would have to do that, one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `NSFetchedResultsController` and a custom `sectionNameKeyPath` which should be a method in your `NSManagedObject` subclass.

The fetchedResultsController can be set up as following:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyObject"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"monthAsString" cacheName:nil];
```

You need to implement the `monthAsString` method in your managedObject subclass. Allocate the NSDateFormatter only once, because it won't perform well if you allocate a new instance for every call.

```
 - (NSString *)monthAsString {
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"MMMM yyyy";
    });

    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:self.date];
    return dateString;
 }
```